# Why has my git commit changed all lines to CRLF?

Tags: git, newline

The project I'm working on has a text file called `pom.xml`. Looking at the history this file has always had every line ending with LF... until recently.

I'm running on Windows and when I installed git bash I took the option to automatically convert to CRLF on checkout and back to LF on commit. I have just checked this as follows:

```
git config core.autocrlf
true
```

The problem is my most recent commit has included the CR characters in the commit and the history tells me that every single line changed.

I just committed some changes to a different text file and I can see correctly that my working copy has CRLF but if I view the history it shows up as just LF. So for this commit the conversion from CRLF to LF has worked. This file is a .drl drools rule file if that makes a difference. I don't understand why it would work on one occasion but not on another. Both files were consistently using LF with previous revisions.

I've had a look at a few other files and noticed I'm not the only one who has had this problem. Some of the other .xml files have at some point switched from LF to CRLF. This messes up the history so I would like to sort this out.

**Edit**

If I look at the commit that contained this `pom.xml` change, I also created two new Java classes. Both of these were committed with CRLF, so each file in the commit has the incorrect line endings. If I check a different commit from around the same time I can see all files (including a mix of new and existing Java classes and .drl text files) have been converted to just LF on the commit.

Comment: take a look at the `.gitattributes` file. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

Comment: I have looked at this file in my reading today. I still don't understand why the conversion from CRLF to LF failed for this one commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The setting core.autocrlf is not properly set when installing git bash. So `git config core.autocrlf` returns true, but `git config --global core.autocrlf` returns blank.

This is fine if you only use git bash as the setting is picked up. However, I had made a commit using EGit within Eclipse and this found the --global setting not set and used the default of false. This is why the behaviour was inconsistent, commits via git bash worked but not via Eclipse.

I fixed it by setting the global setting as follows:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

This has made commits behave whichever tool I use and also Eclipse is behaving when I compare two revisions of a file.